# Why do I get a gap between last element in one form and first element in second form?

Tags: html, css, opera, display

I have this html file:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ff5;
}

form {
  display: inline;
}

#nick_msg {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 90%;
}

#nick {
  width: 20%;
}

#nick input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: #00f;
}

#nick button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
}

#msg {
  width: 80%;
}

#msg input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
}

#msg button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
}

#messages {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="messages">
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>end</li>
</ul>
<div id='nick_msg'>
  <form id='nick' action="">
    <input id="n" /><button>Join</button>
  </form>
  <form id='msg' action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now, I get a gap between "#nick button" and "#msg input" like shown in this screenshot:

[image]

So, I made the content window exactly 1000px and took a look at the other elements. 900px for #nick_msg, 90px for #nick input and button and #msg button and 540px for #msg input, another 90px gap on the right (the black one and another 100px white gap on the outer right). The input and button tags get 10px padding on all sides, so their inner size should be 70px (and 520px for the big one). The form's size is shown as auto x auto, but selecting it only shows a selection box of size 180px or 630px as it should be. But still, there is a small gab between the two forms. <s>I already tried to write both form tags on one line with no spaces in between, no change here.</s> *(not sure about this one anymore, because considering the accepted answer, this should have resolved the issue and in a later test I did, it actually DID.)* So, what's causing the gap and what do I need to change to get rid of that gap?

Browser: Opera 47.0.2631.55 Gentoo/Linux (x86_64)

Note: The screenshot for "#nick" shows a bigger box which could explain the gap. As soon as I put first `</button>` and first `</form>` on same line with no space between, that box shrinks but the gap remains.

Further screenshots:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bvGM.png (body - the image inlined above)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ySx.png (#nick_msg)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaSBt.png (#nick)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/vErgd.png (#nick input)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0O1u.png (#nick button)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/jySAQ.png (#msg)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtMvq.png (#msg input)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUibf.png (#msg button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `font-size: 0` to your `form` and see the magic!

Well, this is due to the *characteristic* space between elements when using *inline* elements - note that you have given `display: inline` to your `form`.

The browser styles for the `form` elements will override the zero font-size or you can do it yourself using `font-size: initial`.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #ff5;
}

form {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0;
}

#nick_msg {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 90%;
}

#nick {
  width: 20%;
}

#nick input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: #00f;
}

#nick button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
}

#msg {
  width: 80%;
}

#msg input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
}

#msg button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
  background: rgb(130, 224, 255);
}

#messages {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="messages">
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>msg</li>
  <li>end</li>
</ul>
<div id='nick_msg'>
  <form id='nick' action="">
    <input id="n" /><button>Join</button>
  </form>
  <form id='msg' action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, what I don't understand yet is: Why? The form tag itself doesn't contain any text, so how in the world can changing font size have an effect here?

Comment: Not only text, but *any* element which is of any *inline* display like `inline`, `inline-block` *flows* like text...

Comment: `<span>Menu</span><span>Feedback</span><span>Help</span>` there is no space between any of the words.

Comment: because there is no *white-space* between them, you must have written the markup in a single line without whitespace between them...

Comment: reread my question ;) - I did try putting all form stuff in one line without spaces in between - same result. However, font-size: 0 solves the issue, but I still don't understand why. And fixing bugs without knowing why the fix works always backfires at some later time. So, I really want to understand the issue here.

Comment: putting `form`s into a single line works too (check the fiddle added above)... let me know if all is ok now :)

Comment: Ok, I tried commenting out the white spaces now, and the gap also vanishes. Don't know why now but not before, but now I know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied the code [here](https://codepen.io/estemon/pen/XaPyxj) and I think (but I'm not sure), if you're talking about the black little vertical line, you have to add the `font-size: 0;` to `form` styling.

```
form {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Try and tell us

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add change your the add a margin property in the CSS for your form.

```
form {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 -0.5em 0 -0.5em;
}
```

That should get rid of the space between the forms on the left and right (since your forms are on the same line). Hope this helps :)