# Inline-block does not line up the same line

Tags: html, css

I use `display: inline-block` for `div.left` - `div.right` and `div.red` - `div.yellow` but none of them are in the same line. I set the width exactly. But it does not work at all.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
.left, .right, .red, .yellow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray
}
.right {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  background: blue;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="red-yellow">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `font-size: 0` to the `container`... as to why read read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements); see a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903586/why-do-i-get-a-gap-between-last-element-in-one-form-and-first-element-in-second/45903840#45903840)

Answer (score 1):

### Update

If you need to keep `inline-block` styles, you need the `.left` and .`right` `div`s to add up to `800px`. The thing with `inline-block` is that it will include white space and add it to the width. This is why the wrapping is still occurring. The following image shows the white space that is causing the wrapping.

[image]

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) to remove white space and make this fit. One way is to add an `HTML` comment between the `.left` and `right` `div`, which removes all white space.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div><!-- 
   --><div class="right">
    <div class="red-yellow">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
.left, .right, .red, .yellow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray
}
.right {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  background: blue;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div><!--
  --><div class="right">
    <div class="red-yellow">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you add `display: flex` to the `.container`, the immediate children (`.left` and `.right`) will align in the same row. The `.right` `div` is `50px` taller than the `.left` `div` because of the explicit width being set (`550px` for `.right`, `500px` for `.left`).

Also, you can remove this, as it will no longer have any effect due to the `flexbox` container.

```css
.left, .right, .red, .yellow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray
}
.right {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  background: blue;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="red-yellow">
      <div class="red"></div>
      <div class="yellow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But you can tell me. Why doesnt my code work. This is my exercise which is only use display: inline-block, other properties does not accept!

Comment: @HiepNguyen I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: @HiepNguyen I'm glad it's working for you. I’d be grateful if you could select my answer as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

if use display: inline-block , there will be some space between the elements. In order to overcome that u can use float property so that every element will be aligned in the same line.

If u want to go with display: inline-block property, you have to reduce the width of .red and .yellow,say for example

```
.red,.yellow{ width: 270px}
```